# SQL Server Mirroring GRANT CONNECT ON ENDPOINT

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

FROM the MIRROR sql ( db in Restoring... )   I can successfully run this

```
ALTER DATABASE ClearWater SET PARTNER = N'TCP://TMPSQL2.caldomain.lcl:5022'
```

Now when I try from the `Principal` sql server

```
ALTER DATABASE ClearWater SET PARTNER = N'TCP://TMPSQL2V.caldomain.lcl:5022'
```

I get this error

`The server network address "TCP://TMPSQL2V.caldomain.lcl:5022" can not be reached or does not exist. Check the network address name and that the ports for the local and remote endpoints are operational.`

> I have opened firewall and I can telnet etc..

Reading articles, and I am trying to do a Grant Connect..  without any luck

GRANT CONNECT ON ENDPOINT::Mirroring TO [caldomain.lcl\sa]

Cannot grant, deny, or revoke permissions to sa, dbo, entity owner, information_schema, sys, or yourself.

1. I don't know if this Grant Connect is even my problem
2. There is a domain called `caldomain` and it is technically same as  `caldomain.lcl`   There are SA accounts on both server (principal and mirror)  ,  I am not sure what to use for an account , create a new account?

> notice principal is   TmpSQL2  and mirror is  TmpSQL2V

Comment: If it is indeed a `grant` issue, I don't think that `sa` is the appropriate grantee. Instead, look at who the service accounts are (i.e. when you look at what account the sqlsrvr.exe process is running under) and if *those* accounts have the appropriate permission. However, given that the error message is saying that it can't even reach the endpoint, I think you're not even getting to the permissions check. That is, you're failing in something like resolving the name `tmpsql2v.caldomain.lcl` to an IP address.

Comment: @BenThul    from the principal `tmpsql2` I can ping `tmpsql2v.caldomain.lcl` and get an ip address...  10.100.56.64   , and then the opposite is true when I ping  tmpsql2.... from  tmpsql2v

Comment: I see that the existing machine is set with sql server and the agent in SSCS to run under `.\Adminstrator`    , even though we all use the database with sa account etc..   ,   my new sql server instance is running under `NT Server\MSSQLSERVER`   Should I change that ?

Comment: Any time I've implemented any sort of HA/DR technology (mirroring, availability groups, log shipping), I've had all servers in the topology use an explicit domain account so I knew what account(s) to grant access to. In your case, it's looks like it's running under some local machine account. Changing them to be domain accounts is its own challenge, though.